# Redux-Thunk unable to get props in component

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have an application with firebase connected. I am able to at each step console log and get see the data from firebase being passed around however when im in the component level it always returns empty.

```
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import { GET_LIST } from './types';



export const getListThunk = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        const teams = [];
        const teamsObj = {};
        var that = this;
        var ref = firebase.database().ref('SignUp/' + "577545cf-c266-4b2e-9a7d-d24e7f8e23a5");
        //var query = ref.orderByChild("uuid");
        console.log("uuid thunk ");

        ref.on('value', function (snapshot) {
            console.log("snap ", snapshot.val())
            snapshot.forEach(function (child) {

                let currentlike = child.val()
                    console.log("schedas ", currentlike)
                    teams.push(currentlike);

                    console.log("teams ",teams);



            });
            dispatch({ type: GET_LIST, payload: teams})
        })


    }

}
```

At all the console log here I am able to receive the information from firebase. The console displays:

[image]

Now I checked my reducer to see if I can see my information there.

```
import { GET_LIST } from '../actions/types';
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    jello: 'hello'
};

const listReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {


    switch (action.type){
        case GET_LIST:
            console.log("action ", action.payload);
            return action.payload;
        default:
        console.log("default ");
            return state;
    }

};

export default listReducer;
```

This console log labeled action shows the payload as well

[image]

So I am again able to see the data in the reducer payload.

Now checking my component I would assume calling this.props would show the data again however it shows up empty.

Component:

```
mport React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    Button,
    SafeAreaView,
    ScrollView,
    Image,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Alert,
    Animated,
    FlatList
} from "react-native";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { getListThunk } from '../actions';
import Form from '../components/Form';
import firebase from "firebase";
import * as theme from '../theme';
import Block from '../components/Block';
import Text from '../components/Text';
import App from "../../App";



class RenderRequests extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.params = this.props;
        uuid2 = this.props.uuid;
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.getListThunk();

    }
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log("did mount " , this.params.uuid)
        var uuid = this.params.uuid;

        //this.props.getListThunk({uuid});

    }


    render() {
        console.log("Component level array " ,this.props)
        return (
            <View>
            <Text> {this.params.uuid} </Text>

            </View>

        );
    }
}

export default connect(null, { getListThunk })(RenderRequests);
```

Now console login this shows an empty array:

[image]

NOTE the UUID in that log file is a UUID I passed as a prop from the previous screen. As you can see the "getListThunk" is empty.

--------**EDIT**------------------------ I have added code based on what Vinicius Cleves has said. However I had to make it {list: state} instead of {list: state.listReducer}

I now see it in my console. However, it seems like it shows up then runs the default action and my state gets reset to nothing. Below is a screenshot of my console:

[image]

If you see my reducer code I am logging when the default action is being called. Why is it being called so many times after the initial 'GET_LIST' action gets called. This keeps replacing my state with the default state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getListThunk is a function, as expected. To access the information as you want in `this.props`, you should provide a mapStateToProps function to connect.

```
export default connect(
  state=>({someVariableName: state.listReducer}), 
  { getListThunk }
)(RenderRequests);
```

Now, the information you were missing on `this.props` will show under `this.props.someVariableName`

Comment: I have implemented your code. I can see it in my console now. Now the issue is that default case is being called for some reason 3 times after the initial state gets created. I feel like we are close to getting this right.

I have edited my original post to show the screenshot. Check my reducer code I am logging when the default action occurs

Comment: It looks like redux is not passing the state to the reducer. Can you share how you create the store and hook up the Provider? Also, is this your only reducer? If not, can you share how you build your rootReducer

Comment: Reading your comments I checked my code. I wasn't creating my store and hooking up the provider at the root level of the app. I moved to to the root level (App.js) and now it works perfectly. Why does it have to be in the root level and not in any other component or screen?